# Using HttpGet returning complete HTML code

Tags: android, web-services, http-get

I am trying to invoke a private web-service in which there's one link I've to access using `GET` method. While using the direct URL on browser (needs to login first), I get the data in JSON format. The URL I am invoking is like this

```
 http://www.example.com/trip/details/860720?format=json
```

The url is working fine, but when I invoke this using `HttpGet`, I am getting the HTML coding of the webpage, instead of the JSON String. The code I am using is as follows:

```
private String runURL(String src,int id) {   //src="http://www.example.com/trip/details/"
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();   
    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(src); 
    String responseBody="";
        BasicHttpParams params=new BasicHttpParams();
        params.setParameter("domain", token); //The access token I am getting after the Login
        params.setParameter("format", "json");
        params.setParameter("id", id);
        try {
                httpget.setParams(params);
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
                responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
                Log.d("runURL", "response " + responseBody); //prints the complete HTML code of the web-page
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        return responseBody;
}
```

Can you tell me what am I doing wrong here??

Comment: what's the content if you try to reach the url with the browser or curl

Comment: it's a json string, if I try to invoke it through browser, which is what it should be on Android also.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try specify Accept & Content-Type in you http header:

```
httpget.setHeader("Accept", "application/json"); // or application/jsonrequest
httpget.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
```

Note that you can use tools like [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) capture and analyse the income and outcome http package, and figure out the exact style of the http header that returns your json response from a standard browser.

**Update:**
You mentioned need login first when using browser, the html content returned is probably the login page (if use basic authentication type, it returns a short html response with status code 401, so a modern browser knows how to handle, more specifically, pop up login prompt to user), so the first try would be checking the  status code of your http response:

```
int responseStatusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
```

Depend on what kind of authentication type you use, you probably need specify login credentials in your http request as well, something like this (if it is a basic authentication):

```
httpClient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(
  new AuthScope("http://www.example.com/trip/details/860720?format=json", 80), 
  new UsernamePasswordCredentials("username", "password");
```