# download file from google sites in an android application programatically

Tags: java, android, download, httpconnection

I need to download a file from Google sites, which is made private ( which: "Only the people listed below can access" ). When I make it accessible to everybody ( without user and pass authentication ), I could download it with e.g. this code:

```
url = new URL("https://user:pass@sites.google.com/site/abc/def.txt");
HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setReadTimeout(7000 );
conn.setConnectTimeout(7000 );
conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
conn.connect();   
InputStream stream = conn.getInputStream();
return stream;
```

... but when I set the private option, e.g. only authenticated user is able to see it, I am not able to download from an app. I am able to see it from browser with the same user and pass. I've tried basic authentication and url/http/https requests listed here:

[Using HttpGet returning complete HTML code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9805300/using-httpget-returning-complete-html-code)
[How to do HTTP authentication in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1968416/how-to-do-http-authentication-in-android/1968873#1968873)
[How to respond to HTTP authentication challenges in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13612213/how-to-respond-to-http-authentication-challenges-in-android)
etc...
With all of them, I get request 200, and I am redirected to login page ( InputStream is the login page ).

Comment: Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I am having similar problems. It seems to redirect to the download popup window by default. Getting HTTP header: "Moved Temporarily", "attredirects", "The document has moved".